# Customize each cell height of a table

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to adjust each cell height according to the dynamic data that comes from web. So, how can I fit the height of cell according to each data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the following method in the delegate

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Have a look at the Apple documentation page [here](http://tinyurl.com/heightForRowAtIndexPath)